# Детали развертывания веб-приложения на сервере

Tags: python, flask

Написал, значит, сайт (flask). Для тренировки. Очень простой - на нем будут лишь переводы каких-то английских, интересных мне статей.

База данных содержит лишь информацию о статье, нет никаких комментариев и вообще личных данных кого бы то ни было (возможно, пока). 
Но вот вопрос:

Как пополняется БД у такого приложения (имеется скрипт по ее пополнению)? Как я понял, хостинг выделяет для меня какое-то место у себя на серверах, а сама программа находится у меня на компьютере, поэтому я смогу изменять БД на своем компьютере и эти изменения вступят в силу и на сайте?

Comment: «сама программа находится у меня на компьютере» — нет. Ну то есть да, делать, как вы описали, теоретически тоже можно. Но не нужно. И flask, и база данных обычно хранятся и выполняются на сервере (на хостинге) независимо ни от вашего компьютера, ни от чего-либо ещё. Захочется что-то изменить — идёте на сервер и меняете, а ваш компьютер здесь ни при чём

Comment: А вообще у вас два вопроса в одном, для Stack Overflow это неформат. Разделите их на два отдельных вопроса (хотя что-то похожее на второй вопрос я вроде когда-то уже видел)

Comment: По большому счету вашему сайту XSS никак не угрожает. Хацкеры умеют только алерта добиться! А вот крутить XSS to RCE - ну никак не смогут) Так что не переживайте!

Comment: @misdeed, окей, от подобных уязвимостей защищен - а другие? Разве их не существует?

Comment: @ГошаОбыночный, уязвимостей существует несчетное количество. И чем больше кода/чем больше проект - тем больше в нём уязвимостей!

Comment: @misdeed, а какие конкретно (проект очень маленький, кода минимум, большая часть - верстка)? Самые частые и простые, чтобы хотя бы от них защититься

Comment: @ГошаОбыночный задайте другой вопрос с соответствующей меткой. Я не собираюсь в комментариях отвечать на ваши вопросы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно для наполнения бд создают админку, либо пользуются [Flask-Admin](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin). Таким образом, и сайт, и БД будут находится на хостинге, и управлять вы всем будете с хостинга.

Также можно подключиться к удаленной БД на хостинге и с локального компьютера, и рулить данными локально. Но первый вариант предпочтительней.